# Plotting galactic latitude in Ra vs Dec plane

Tags: declination, right-ascension, star-cluster, polarization

I have an open cluster with calculated percentage of polarization and position angle. I want to have it's scatter plot in Ra vs Dec plane and superimpose a galactic parallel on it. How to plot the galactic parallel? Like the line b=-0.14 deg shown in the figure. I have used python for the scatter plot and also I have plotted the percentage of polarization and position angle but I am unable to the plot the galactic latitude line. Can anyone help me in this regard? [image]

Comment: Pick a point on your plot that you'd like th galactic parallel to pass through. Convert equatorial to galactic using widely available conversion equations. Then pick a point same latitude different longitude and convert galactic to equatorial. Then you have two points on the parallel. For the scale you're showing the different longitude should be about 1/4 degree different.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much. I was able to do it.